# How to Deseralize XML nodes of different names to same base type

Tags: c#, xml, attributes, deserialization, nodes

I'm having trouble finding an example online that explains exactly how to configure the XmlSerializer to Deserialize XML the way I want.

I want to deserialize this XML into a `Fruits` or at least a `List<Fruit>`

```
<fruits>
  <apple>{fruitstuff}</apple>
  <orange>{fruitstuff}</orange>
  <pear>{fruitstuff}</pear>
<fruits>
```

I imagine a model that looks like this

```
class Fruits : List<Fruit> {}

class Fruit {
  {fruitstuff}
}

class Apple : Fruit {}

class Orange : Fruit {}

class Pear : Fruit {}
```

The problem I am running into is some combination of XmlSerlization configuration and XML Attributing. When I provide an XmlSeralizer the XML can be read with out throwing an error however it does not recognize the collection of fruits. The collection will contain zero elements.

```
var seralizer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Fruits), new XmlRootAttribute("Fruits"));
```

My question to the internet is, how do I configure the serializer to recognize and deserialize like nodes into a collection of base types?

I would rather have an elaborately configured custom serializer than an XmlAttributed model. I might want to use the model with different formats other than XML. Having xml attributes all over my model is I think less elegant than a targeted serialization implementation.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add `<fruit>` element to wrap multiple `<fruits>` elements
2. Add `XmlRoot` and `XmlElement` attributes to corresponding clases.

My sample code and it works:

```cs
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string xml = @"
        <fruit>
            <fruits>
              <apple>
                 <attr1>1</attr1>
                 <attr2>2</attr2>
              </apple>
              <orange>
                 <attr1>3</attr1>
                 <attr2>4</attr2>
              </orange>
              <pear>
                 <attr1>5</attr1>
                 <attr2>6</attr2>
              </pear>
            </fruits> 
            <fruits>
              <apple>
                 <attr1>7</attr1>
                 <attr2>8</attr2>
              </apple>
              <orange>
                 <attr1>9</attr1>
                 <attr2>10</attr2>
              </orange>
              <pear>
                 <attr1>11</attr1>
                 <attr2>12</attr2>
              </pear>
            </fruits>   
        </fruit>
            ";
        var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Fruit));
        using (var reader = new StringReader(xml))
        {
            var myFruits = (Fruit)ser.Deserialize(reader);
        }

        Console.Read();
    }
}


[XmlRoot("fruit")]
public class Fruit
{
    [XmlElement("fruits")]
    public List<Fruits> Fruits { get; set; }
}


public class Fruits
{
    [XmlElement("apple")]
    public Apple Apple { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("orange")]
    public Orange Orange { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("pear")]
    public Pear Pear { get; set; }
}

public class FruitCommonProperty
{
    [XmlElement("attr1")]
    public string Attr1 { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("attr2")]
    public string Attr2 { get; set; }
}

public class Apple : FruitCommonProperty { }

public class Orange : FruitCommonProperty { }

public class Pear : FruitCommonProperty { }
```

Comment: Part of the problem is that the input XML is an external input that is provided as-is. The example provided is a dumbed-down version of the real-world problem. One of the constraints is that the XML structure is not modifiable. If I could change the structure of the XML, I would format it completely differently.